# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google' import google.auth

Tags: gcloud

i am trying to make it access google sheets but it cant find a module named google in python

import google.auth
ive tried a lot of pip commands and general tutorials and help videos on youtube however still cant get it to work im using vsc, with google cloud installed and python

Comment: It is also having other import issues with google and selenium https://prnt.sc/WGg12rjUniwW

Comment: You need to add sample code (at the minimum, the bit where you're importing a google package or library), and also tell us at what point you get the error and what your environment/setup is